# Ternary search tree in java

Tags: java, ternary-representation

I'm basically working on ternary implementation in java .I don't wanna use ajax. 
I am working on bigram model and so want to autocomplete the next alphabet.Can anyone suggest how to implement ???

Thnks

Comment: Your question really doesn't make any sense. You want to build a ternary search tree? Why not use an existing B-tree library? What does AJAX have to do with anything? What do bigrams have to do with either of those things?

Comment: I don't know anything about ternary search tree and yeah by build if you mean populate and then search then I want to build one. B-tree?? could that work?? as far as I've read about it ternary search tree seems to be solution. I've read ternary by ajax so just mentioned it I don't want to use this. My project requires use of bigrams and I was thinking of it to use a key value maybe